# bash to move specific files to folder based on match in another

Tags: bash, mv

I am trying to mv each of the `.vcf` files in the `variants folder` to the folder in `/home/cmccabe/f2` that the `.vcf` id is found in `file`. `$2` in `file` will always have the id of a `.vcf` in the variants folder. The line in `file` staring with `R_2019` up to the `-v5.6` will always be an exact match to a folder in `/home/cmccabe/f2`. There may be multiple folders in `/home/cmccabe/f2` but will only have one match in `file`. There also may be mulitple id's but always only one `.vcf` in `/home/cmccabe/f1/variants`.

When a match is found between the folder in `/home/cmccabe/f2` and the `R_2019` in `file`, then the id(s) in `$2` will be found in `/home/cmccabe/f1/variants` as a `.vcf`. Each `.vcf` is then moved to the matching folder in `/home/cmccabe/f2` in a new sub-folder `variants`. The `bash` does execute but no files are moved. Thank you :).

**file** in /home/cmccabe/f1

```
IonCode_0007 19-0004-La-Fi
IonCode_0009 19-0005-Last-Firs
IonCode_0013 190320-Control
R_2019_03_12_13_59_54_user_S5-0271-100-v5.6_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xx_x_xxx
```

**variants folder** in `/home/cmccabe/f1`

```
19-0004-La-Fi.vcf
19-0005-Last-Firs.vcf
190320-Control.vcf
```

**current structure** of `/home/cmccabe/f2`

```
R_2019_03_12_13_59_54_user_S5-0271-100   ---parent directory ---
   - bam    --- sub-folder ---
   - qc     --- sub-folder ---
```

**desired structure** of `/home/cmccabe/f2`

```
R_2019_03_12_13_59_54_user_S5-0271-100   ---parent directory ---
   - bam    --- sub-folder ---
   - qc     --- sub-folder ---
   - variants    --- new sub-folder ---
     - 19-0004-La-Fi.vcf
     - 19-0005-Last-Firs.vcf
     - 190320-Control.vcf
```

**possible bash**

```
for file in /home/cmccabe/f1/variants/*.vcf ; do
  # Grab file prefix
  bname=$(basename $file) # strip of path
  VCF="$(echo $bname|cut -d. -f1)" # remove .vcf extension
  f=$(printf '%s' /home/cmccabe/f1/file/${VCF})  ## # Find matching id
  FILE2=$(awk '{print $2}' $f) # set VCF lookup to column
    for RDIR in /home/cmccabe/f1/file/R_2019* ; do FOLDER=${RDIR%%-v5.6*}; done  ## trim R_2019 line in file from -v5.6 and store in FOLDER
  if [[ $VCF = $FILE2 ]] # only execute file on match
  then
      mkdir -p /home/cmccabe/f2/$FOLDER/variants  ## create variants sub-folder
       mv /home/cmccabe/f1/file/$VCF /home/cmccabe/f2/$FOLDER/variants  ## move vcf to folder
  fi  ## end if
done  ## close loop
```

Comment: "This is the last step of a procedure that I am stuck on." This refers to i have a bunch of scripts that create, format, and organize folders/files and now I am trying to move them to there specific location (part I am stuck on). The `possible bash` does  execute  but nothing is moved. Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much :).

Comment: I made some edits in the post and updated `DIR` to a path. Thank you :).

Comment: The loop `for RDIR in`... is still wrong, it effectively does nothing. The corresponding `done` should probably be between `fi` and the final `done`.

Comment: What would you suggest.... i am not able to figure it out. Thank you :).

Comment: For debugging the script I suggest to execute it with `bash -x YourScript` or insert a line `set -x` before `for file in`... and execute it. This instructs the shell to print every command before executing. With this output you might be able to see if it does what you want and maybe find out what is going wrong.

Comment: `set -x` shows the variables are not being populated in my script... for example `$VCF` is empty. So I know what the issue is but not really how to fix it. Thank you :).

Comment: Please don't answer in comments. Add this information to your question. Add more details. If `$VCF` is empty, show the other variables. Maybe show a reasonable piece of the output of running the script with `set -x`.

Comment: I will write a new script and start a new thread after doing some troubleshooting.  Thank you very much :).